# Having issue with twitteR R package, error with "language" not being definded

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to retreive Tweets for a college assisgnment.

I am having the following error:

```
Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘language’, should be from class “character” or a subclass (was class “NULL”)
```

I think this is an error with either Twitter updating the API or twitteR being out of date.

The packages devtools and twitteR have previously been installed.

This is my code:

```
setwd("H:/DAD_R")

#### Simple Twitter Example ####

#install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

#install_github("geoffjentry/twitteR")
library(twitteR)

api_key <- "<censored>"
api_secret <- "<censored>"
access_token <- "<censored>"
access_token_secret <- "<censored>"

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

keywords <- c("GameOfThrones", "#GoT")
tweets <- searchTwitter(keywords[1], n = 1500)
```

Is there a way to remedy this?

Thanks.

Debug: [Image](https://ibb.co/MCcDBd2)

Comment: [This is what happens when I debug](https://ibb.co/MCcDBd2)

Comment: I userstand the twitteR package has not been updated since 2016. Is there a very similar package to use so I don't need to edit my code too much?

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use `rtweet` instead.

I was trying to retrieve Tweets.

Here is the main difference I've found;

**twitteR:**

```
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

keywords <- c("GameOfThrones", "#GoT")
tweets <- searchTwitter(keywords[1], n = 1500)
```

**rtweet:**

```
token <- create_token(appName, consumerKey, consumerSecret)

keywords <- c("GameOfThrones", "#GoT") 
tweets <- search_tweets(keywords[1], n = 1500, include_rts = FALSE, token = token)
```

*Note: In your app settings on dev.twitter.com, your callback address has to be exactly:

**http://127.0.0.1:1410**

I suspect that's the localhost for R/R Studio, but I'm not sure. 
After the first retrieval, you'll be asked to sign in to your normal Twitter account to give your app access to your account.*